# Documentation of functions defined with functools partialmethod

Tags: python

I have tried to somehow get a documentation for a partialmethod to work. My current code is

```
from functools import partialmethod

class Fun(object):

  def test(self, num):
    """
    I have a documentation
    """
    return num

  test2 = partialmethod(test, num=10)
  test2.__doc__ = """Blub"""

  test3 = partialmethod(test, num=20)
```

But if I run

```
a = Fun()
a.test2.__doc__ # only returns the partials documentation not "Blub"
Fun.test2.__doc__ # gives nothing
```

and Sphinx lists them using `autoclass` as `undocumented members`.

I have read https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects and https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod but does that mean that there is *no way* of getting documentations into partialmethods or am I just too stupid about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to set a docstring on a `partialmethod` object. That's because `partialmethod` is a class written in Python, and instances of classes get their docstring from the class's `__doc__`, not from a `__doc__` attribute on the instances. Functions behave differently, with the `__doc__` attribute of the function object being looked at.

Depending on how complicated your use of `partialmethod` is, you may be able to write your own version that returns a function, rather than an instance, thus allowing you to customize the documentation by assigning to the `__doc__` attribute.

Here's a quick version I've thrown together with only basic testing. I think it works for common cases (e.g. where `func` is an actual function), but it probably won't be as flexible as the regular `partialmethod` type, so you should double check that it does everything you need it to do:

```
import functools

def my_partialmethod(func, *args1, **kwargs1):
    @functools.wraps(func)  # copy attributes to start, they can be overwritten later
    def method(self, *args2, **kwargs2):
        return func(self, *args1, *args2, **kwargs1, **kwargs2)
    return method
```

The multiple unpacking in the call to `func` is only legal in Python 3.5. In older Python versions, you'll have to merge the arguments yourself with something like this:

```
    def method(self, *args2, **kwargs2):
        kwargs = kwargs1.copy()
        kwargs.update(kwargs2)
        return func(self, *(args1+args2), **kwargs)
```

Here's an example use:

```
class Test(object):
    def method1(self, arg):
        "docstring1"
        print(arg)

    method2 = my_partial_method(method1, "foo")
    method2.__name__ = "method2"
    method2.__doc__ = "docstring2"

    method3 = my_partial_method(method1, arg="bar")
    method3.__name__ = "method3"
    method3.__doc__ = "docstring3"
```

You can of course pick which attributes to overwrite. I'm not sure if using `functools.wraps` is a good idea or not, as it may copy over a bunch of invalid attributes, beyond the ones I'm modifying in my example.

Comment: I actually had such a decorator (ok, it was a bit different) before using `functools.partialmethod`. But that approach has some downsides - i.e. it copies the original function signature (which normally is a good thing but not with partials). But it seems very sad that the partialmethod is not capable of providing such functionality. Especially because `partial` allows such an usage - but only for functions not methods. But nevertheless many thanks for your answer and if no other possibility presents itself I will accept your answer tomorrow. :-)

Comment: Yeah, my function is essentially `partial` with a special case for `self`. It should work find when wrapping ordinary methods, but won't work if you're wrapping something like a `staticmethod` or another descriptor that doesn't expect to get `self`. If the `wraps` call causes more trouble than good, you can remove it (the signature of the wrapper function will then be `(*args2, **kwargs2)`, which may or may not be an improvement).